# Delete a file after a File response

Tags: file, jax-rs, resteasy

I want to delete a file after a Resteasy put request.
My code:

```
@PUT
@Path("/audioconverter")
public File audioConverter(@Context HttpServletRequest request, File file,
        @QueryParam("codec") String codec,....

        ...
   return aFile();
   }
```

After the return I want to delete aFile() in the filesystem. How can I do that?

Comment: You probably need to wait with deleting the file until it won't be used any more.

Comment: After it is returned it wont be used any more... I need something like a "afterreturn" event.

Comment: Done it with:

return new StreamingOutput(){
public void write(java.io.OutputStream arg0).{
... Streaming and file deleting...
   }
  };

Comment: @user1071250: Please post and approve your answer below so that the question can be marked as answered.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Following some advice from above I was able to do the following:

```
    File zipDirectory = new File(outputZipFolder);

    StreamingOutput stream = new StreamingOutput() {
        @Override
        public void write(OutputStream output) throws IOException, WebApplicationException {
            java.nio.file.Path path = Paths.get(outputZipFile);
            byte[] data = Files.readAllBytes(path);
            output.write(data);
            output.flush();
            FileUtils.cleanDirectory(zipDirectory);

        }
    };
```